# Alternative to signalfd

Tags: macos, signals

Is there an alternative to `signalfd` (not available on Mac OS X)? I'm multiplexing I/O using `select` and would like to receive signals in some synchronized fashion.

Comment: You can emulate it with a pipe a dedicated thread and a suitable signal mask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`man kqueue` and look for `EVFILT_SIGNAL` there.

The descriptor returned by `kqueue()` should be `poll()`able/`select()`able. Events can be registered and read out using the `kevent()` call.

[Original kqueue paper](http://people.freebsd.org/~jlemon/papers/kqueue.pdf)

P.S. I hope I'm not off by much, had no chance to use the kqueue myself yet.